# Phonegap and Xcode

Tags: xcode, jquery-mobile

I currently have a series of 8 separate html files, with the idea that each one is a separate page in an iPad app. I have used jQuery Mobile to implement the page swipe between pages by using the 'data-next' and 'data-prev' attribute. However, the results are not great as i sometimes get a page flicker when i swipe, and css animations are very choppy when I test it on an actual iPad. I am also getting a 1 second delay before the actual swipe happens. I know JQM has a default delay of 300ms, but this is waaay longer! I have tried using the css 'translate3d' technique on animated elements, but it doesn't seem to fix it. I'm putting it down to JQM just being buggy as hell.

So my question is this..Is it possible to bring these files into Xcode, as separate independent html files, and implement the page swipe within Xcode itself?

Answer (score 0):

No Not possible.
XCode allows you to create/edit UI and Transitions of cocoa touch controls only. However you can **just edit** these html/javascript files in XCode.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I thought it may be possible to create a series of UI web views and implement them that way.